# Error - Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm not a developer but I'm here to find help with great developers . I do very basic SQL but complex ones I've got no clue as below.

```
SELECT     aualdocs.fmt_acc, aualdocs.ddn_cd1, dbo.aualrefn.dsc_no1, aunrmast.nam_fam, RTRIM(aunrmast.nam_gv1) + ' ' + RTRIM(COALESCE (aunrmast.nam_gv2, '')) 
                  AS nam_gvn, aunrmast.dte_brt, aunrmast.sex, aunrmast.nam_ttl, 
                  CASE WHEN res_ad1 LIKE 'C/%' OR res_ad1 LIKE 'PO %' THEN res_ad1 END AS pst_nme, 
                  CASE WHEN NOT(res_ad1 LIKE 'C/%' OR res_ad1 LIKE 'PO %') THEN LEFT(res_ad1,PATINDEX('% %',res_ad1)) END as pst_num,
                  CASE WHEN NOT(res_ad1 LIKE 'C/%' OR res_ad1 LIKE 'PO %') THEN SUBSTRING(res_ad1,CHARINDEX(' ',res_ad1),charindex(' ',res_ad1,charindex(' ',res_ad1)+1) - CHARINDEX(' ',res_ad1)) END AS pst_str,
                  CASE WHEN NOT(res_ad1 LIKE 'C/%' OR res_ad1 LIKE 'PO %') THEN REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(RTRIM(res_ad1)),PATINDEX('% %',REVERSE(RTRIM(res_ad1)))-1)) END AS pst_typ,
                  REPLACE(res_ad2,aunrmast.pst_cde,'') AS pst_loc,
                  aunrmast.pst_cde, auprstad.bld_nme, auprstad.pcl_unt, auprstad.unt_alp, auprstad.hou_num, auprstad.hou_alp, auprstad.hou_end, auprstad.end_alp, ausrmast.str_nme, 
                  ausrmast.str_typ, RTRIM(ausrsubr.sbr_nme) + '  ' + ausrsubr.sta_nme AS sub_sta, ausrsubr.pst_cde AS Expr1, aualdocs.ddf_cd2, aualdocs.dda_cd2, auallnks.lnk_typ, 
                  aunrlink.nar_num, auprlink.pcl_num, aualdocs.det_dte, aualdocs.dte_no2, aualdocs.ddn_cd2
FROM         dbo.aualdocs AS aualdocs INNER JOIN
                  dbo.auallnks AS auallnks ON aualdocs.fmt_acc = auallnks.src_acc INNER JOIN
                  dbo.aunrlink AS aunrlink ON auallnks.src_acc = aunrlink.mdu_fmt INNER JOIN
                  dbo.aunrmast AS aunrmast ON aunrlink.nar_num = aunrmast.nar_num INNER JOIN
                  dbo.auprlink AS auprlink ON aualdocs.fmt_acc = auprlink.mdu_fmt INNER JOIN
                  dbo.auprstad AS auprstad ON auprlink.pcl_num = auprstad.pcl_num INNER JOIN
                  dbo.ausrmast AS ausrmast ON auprstad.str_num = ausrmast.str_num AND auprstad.str_blk = ausrmast.str_blk INNER JOIN
                  dbo.ausrsubr AS ausrsubr ON ausrmast.sbr_num = ausrsubr.sbr_num INNER JOIN
                  dbo.aualrefn ON aualdocs.ddf_cd1 = dbo.aualrefn.ref_val
WHERE     (aualdocs.doc_typ = 90) AND (auallnks.lnk_typ = 151) AND (aualdocs.det_cde = 'APPR') AND (dbo.aualrefn.ref_typ = 'wrd_num')
```

This query was working fine initially, but recently when triggered it was giving out an Error:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

I've got no idea where to start looking. Hopefully someone can assist.

If anyone has an idea, you may need to copy and paste your solutions in the comments for me to try it out on my DB so see if that works. I'm running this is MSSQL using SQL Studio.

Comment: Minimize... Which row is the problem row, and what data causes it.

Comment: Do a binary search! Remove half of the query, did the error disappear or not? Loop.

Comment: Who wrote this code? You or someone else? If someone else, why don't you ask "someone else"? There are obvious assumptions on which the code is based. You will either need to correct those assumptions or correct the data. Pick a path first.  Are there rows where res_ad1 does not have any spaces?

Comment: I tried to troubleshoot by removing the top pars of the query and putting in one by one.

Found out this section is the issue which is causing the Error.

Any idea how to fix this?

CASE WHEN NOT(res_ad1 LIKE 'C/%' OR res_ad1 LIKE 'PO %') THEN REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(RTRIM(res_ad1)),PATINDEX('% %',REVERSE(RTRIM(res_ad1)))-1)) END AS pst_typ,

Comment: Try with replacing it with `REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(RTRIM(res_ad1)), IIF((PATINDEX('% %',REVERSE(RTRIM(res_ad1)))-1) > 0, (PATINDEX('% %',REVERSE(RTRIM(res_ad1)))-1), 0)))`.

Answer (score 1):

Update `LEFT` & `SUBSTRING` functions in your query. Try like below. It seems that second parameter value in `LEFT` or third parameter value in `SUBSTRING` is negative value.

```
SELECT     aualdocs.fmt_acc, aualdocs.ddn_cd1, dbo.aualrefn.dsc_no1, aunrmast.nam_fam, RTRIM(aunrmast.nam_gv1) + ' ' + RTRIM(COALESCE (aunrmast.nam_gv2, '')) 
        AS nam_gvn, aunrmast.dte_brt, aunrmast.sex, aunrmast.nam_ttl, 
        CASE WHEN res_ad1 LIKE 'C/%' OR res_ad1 LIKE 'PO %' THEN res_ad1 END AS pst_nme, 
        CASE WHEN NOT(res_ad1 LIKE 'C/%' OR res_ad1 LIKE 'PO %') THEN LEFT(res_ad1, IIF(PATINDEX('% %',res_ad1) > 0, PATINDEX('% %',res_ad1), 0)) END as pst_num,
        CASE WHEN NOT(res_ad1 LIKE 'C/%' OR res_ad1 LIKE 'PO %') THEN SUBSTRING(res_ad1, CHARINDEX(' ',res_ad1), IIF(charindex(' ',res_ad1, charindex(' ',res_ad1)+1) - CHARINDEX(' ',res_ad1) > 0, charindex(' ',res_ad1, charindex('',res_ad1)+1) - CHARINDEX(' ',res_ad1), 0))  END AS pst_str,
        CASE WHEN NOT(res_ad1 LIKE 'C/%' OR res_ad1 LIKE 'PO %') THEN REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(RTRIM(res_ad1)), IIF((PATINDEX('% %',REVERSE(RTRIM(res_ad1)))-1) > 0, (PATINDEX('% %',REVERSE(RTRIM(res_ad1)))-1), 0))) END AS pst_typ,
        REPLACE(res_ad2,aunrmast.pst_cde,'') AS pst_loc,
        aunrmast.pst_cde, auprstad.bld_nme, auprstad.pcl_unt, auprstad.unt_alp, auprstad.hou_num, auprstad.hou_alp, auprstad.hou_end, auprstad.end_alp, ausrmast.str_nme, 
        ausrmast.str_typ, RTRIM(ausrsubr.sbr_nme) + '  ' + ausrsubr.sta_nme AS sub_sta, ausrsubr.pst_cde AS Expr1, aualdocs.ddf_cd2, aualdocs.dda_cd2, auallnks.lnk_typ, 
        aunrlink.nar_num, auprlink.pcl_num, aualdocs.det_dte, aualdocs.dte_no2, aualdocs.ddn_cd2
FROM         dbo.aualdocs AS aualdocs INNER JOIN
        dbo.auallnks AS auallnks ON aualdocs.fmt_acc = auallnks.src_acc INNER JOIN
        dbo.aunrlink AS aunrlink ON auallnks.src_acc = aunrlink.mdu_fmt INNER JOIN
        dbo.aunrmast AS aunrmast ON aunrlink.nar_num = aunrmast.nar_num INNER JOIN
        dbo.auprlink AS auprlink ON aualdocs.fmt_acc = auprlink.mdu_fmt INNER JOIN
        dbo.auprstad AS auprstad ON auprlink.pcl_num = auprstad.pcl_num INNER JOIN
        dbo.ausrmast AS ausrmast ON auprstad.str_num = ausrmast.str_num AND auprstad.str_blk = ausrmast.str_blk INNER JOIN
        dbo.ausrsubr AS ausrsubr ON ausrmast.sbr_num = ausrsubr.sbr_num INNER JOIN
        dbo.aualrefn ON aualdocs.ddf_cd1 = dbo.aualrefn.ref_val
WHERE     (aualdocs.doc_typ = 90) AND (auallnks.lnk_typ = 151) AND (aualdocs.det_cde = 'APPR') AND (dbo.aualrefn.ref_typ = 'wrd_num')
```

Comment: Hi Karan, thanks for the assist it's coming up with another issue saying incorrect syntax near '>'.

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check now.